# process output losing unicode characters

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, 7zip

I have a following stripped down snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Echo
    {
        public List<string> Run(string arg)
        {
            var output = new List<string>();

            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"/C echo {arg}");

            var x = new UnicodeEncoding(false, true, true);

            var p = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
                {
                    Arguments = x.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, x, bytes)),
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
                }
            };

            p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, a) =>
            {
                if (a.Data != null) output.Add(a.Data);
            };

            p.Start();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            p.WaitForExit();
            p.Close();

            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, with a unicode character as input, the character is lost:

```
var dot = "•";
var echo = new Echo();

var result = echo.Run(dot)?.FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine($"[{dot}] [{result}] {dot == result}");
```

Any ideas on how to 'preserve' these?

Comment: I don't have a real answer, but if you set CreateNoWindow = false, the problem goes away. CreateNoWindow = true seems to cause the process to output ASCII text (verified by reading from p.StandardOutput.BaseStream), but I don't know why that would be.

Comment: Also, there's no need to mess around with encodings. Arguments = $"/C echo {arg}" works just fine.

Comment: @glenebob Setting `CreateNoWindow = false` makes no difference for me, still the same issue (env sensitive? I'm on Win 10 Pro 1709). As for the encodings - yes, these were my attampts to try to solve the issue.

Comment: Interesting. I am also running Windows 10 pro, 1709.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that echo uses an encoding that is not compatible with the encoding of the provided param.

In general, the app called by process.Start() needs to be able to output data using a desired encoding.

In my case it was 7zip file listing. Unicode characters in the path were 'lost' when using `l -slt ...`. When using `l -slt ... -scsUTF-8 -sccUTF-8` solved the case.